# ngRepeat iterate with two objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to figure out on how to do some like this.

If I have a array of data

```
[{complexName: value, complexName2: value}, {complexName: value, complexName2: value}];
```

And another array

```
[{display: "easy name2", bind:"complexName2"}, {display: "easy name", bind:"complexName"}]
```

I want to use a angular ng-repeat to loop between the two arrays and make a table, something like this:

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="obj2 in object2">
                {{obj2.display}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj1 in object1 WHERE obj1.key == obj2.bind">
            <td>{{obj1.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any advices on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this fairly easy by iterating over `object2` twice and using [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) which is made available to us via `ng-repeat`.

Consider the following:

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="obj2 in object2">
        {{obj2.display}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="obj2 in object2">
        {{object1[$index][obj2.bind]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming the indexes in `object1` align with those specified in `object2`, I believe this is what you're attempting to accomplish.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.object1 = [
    {complexName: 'value1', complexName2: 'value2'},
    {complexName: 'value3', complexName2: 'value4'}
  ];

  $scope.object2 = [
    {display: "easy name", bind: "complexName"},
    {display: "easy name2", bind: "complexName2"}
  ];
}
```

```css
tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="obj2 in object2">
          {{obj2.display}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="obj2 in object2">
          {{object1[$index][obj2.bind]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Sean3z !

We can't assume that, the indexes maybe be different, like in the sample objects.

Comment: @LucasFreitas If you click on the `Show code snippet` link in the proposed answer, you'll see that I'm using the sample objects. Or are you implying we can't assume the object from `object1[0]` corresponds to `object2[0]`? If not, then I doubt there's any way you can relate the two pieces of data in their given format.

Comment: I'm implying, sometimes they'll not correspond at the same index.

I'm thinking on make a loop on my Object2, and foreach iterate I will loop all keys from Object1 and check, if they are equal, I will "build" a third object to use it on the table.

Answer (score 0):

** SOLUTION **

Following @Sean3z idea on if the object2 (display labels) match the order of the keys on object1 (data) we could simple use it on repeat, I just made it happens.

Example!

```
ArrayData = [{complexName: value, complexName2: value},
             {complexName: value, complexName2: value}];

ArrayLabels = [{display: "easy name2", bind:"complexName2"},
               {display: "easy name", bind:"complexName"}];
```

First of all, I create a new object and set it keys to match as my ArrayLabels.bind

```
var objAux = {};
for (var x = 0; x < arrayLabels.length; x++) {
    objAux[arrayLabels[x].bind] = null;
}

//output: {complexName2: null, complexName: null}
```

Then, create a new array to store your ordered data and fill it with arrayData.

```
var orderedData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
   for (key in arrayData[i]) {
      obj[key] = arrayData[i][key];
   }
   //Each time i ends the loop on the object, I push it into my array.
   var helper = angular.copy(obj);
   orderedData.push(helper);
}
//After all loops, my $scope.data receive my data.
$scope.data = orderedData;
```

Finally, I just need to populate my table, because the order of the objects match.

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="label in arrayLabels">
        {{label.display}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in data">
      <td ng-repeat="value in obj">
        {{value}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```